# Stumped on how to put items from API data into list to display them to a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm learning to use APIs with the RecipePuppy API and trying to display the results to a webpage. I can't get the individual results into a list in order to display them.

This is in the controller and works fine:

```
public string GetData()
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://www.recipepuppy.com/api/?i=onions,garlic&q=omelet&p=3");
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string ApiText = rd.ReadToEnd();

            return ApiText;
        }
```

This is what I think I'm having problems with. Also in the controller. I'm just not really sure I understand the whole JToken thing properly. Recipe is a model created by me 
 for storing the object.

```
   public List<Recipe> ConvertAPItoRecipes(string APIText)
        {
            JToken t = JToken.Parse(APIText);
            Recipe r = new Recipe();
            List<JToken> recipes = t["title"].ToList();
            //r.Title = t["title"].ToString();
            List<Recipe> r2 = new List<Recipe>();

            foreach(JToken x in recipes)
            {
                Recipe re = new Recipe();
                re.Title = x["title"].ToString();
                string temp = x["ingredients"].ToString();
                List<string> temp2 = temp.Split(',').ToList();
                re.Ingredients = temp2;
                r2.Add(re);
            }

            return r2;
        }
```

Heres the action in the controller. I added an object just to see if the list was displaying properly

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Recipe> recipes = ConvertAPItoRecipes(GetData());
            Recipe r = new Recipe();

            r.Title = "Steamed Hams";
            recipes.Add(r);
            ViewBag.num = recipes.Count();
            return View(recipes);
        }
```

Here is the view. I added the viewbag.num to list the number of items in the list just to confirm it was empty (it reads 1 with the 'steam hams' object I added myself.

```
@model List<Recipe>

@ViewBag.num
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<div>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title) 
</div>
}
```

I expect the list of recipes containing onions and garlic to be displayed on the index. It seems the list would display, but it's empty, and I'm stumped on how to populate it.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: looks like it should work to me. Add a few more manual recipies and then some static text in the loop. Do you see that static text recipies.count number of times?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are actually getting results in this line of code?

```
List<JToken> recipes = t["title"].ToList();
```

It works if you change it to:

```
List<JToken> recipes = t["results"].ToList();
```